# Returning Data Until N'th Occurence of Character X

Tags: unix, sed, awk, grep

Withing a directory I have multiple files that have multiple version numbers within the files. I am grepping each file within the directory for these version numbers, sorting them in order to get the most recent version number, and then piping that into 'tail -1' to only the most recent version number and not every grep result.

The data looks something like this:

file1: asdf garbage 1.2.4.1 garbagetext asdf

file2: fsdaf  garbage asdfsda 4.3.2.10 fdsaf

and so on. I have already accomplished extracting the most recent version number. I did this with the following:

```
grep -o '[0-9]\{1,\}\.[0-9]\{1,\}\.[0-9]\{1,\}\.[0-9]\{1,\}' * | sort | tail -1
```

The next part is what I am having trouble on. I am trying to extract the number (whether it be one number character or two number characters) before the first period and return that result. Then, I am assuming with a slightly different command do the same thing but for the number after the first period. And again for the number after the second period and finally after the third period.

I have little to no experience with sed or awk, but after a little research I believe either one of these tools are the way to accomplish this.

Thank you!

Edit: Alright I got it, but I am certain this can be done in a much easier way. What I have is the following:

```
grep -o '[0-9]\{1,\}\.[0-9]\{1,\}\.[0-9]\{1,\}\.[0-9]\{1,\}' * | sort | tail -1 | grep -o '[0-9]\{1,\}' | sed -n 2p
```

or sed -n 1p, 3p, 4p depending on which value I want.

Comment: your grep line may fail if there are two numbers at beginning. e.g. 12.3.4.555 and 3.4.5.77. I think your grep|sort|tail will give you the later one, which is not the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

to get the lastest version number:

```
grep  -P -o "\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+" * |sed 's/.*://g'|awk -F'.' '{v[$0]=($1"."$2$3$4)+0;}END{m=0;for(x in v)if(v[x]>m){m=v[x];n=x;}print n}'
```

to extract numbers:

```
kent$  echo "10.2.30.4"|awk -F'.' -v OFS="\n" '$1=$1'    
10
2
30
4
```

you can put the two line together.

Answer (score 0):

To extract a version number, without having to know how many dots are in it, I would use

```
grep -o '[0-9.]\+' filename | sort --version-sort | tail -1
```

(assuming you have GNU sort, with the `--version-sort` option)

To get just the major version number, pipe the above into one of

```
sed 's/\..*//'
while read line; do echo ${line%%.*}; done
```